# How to pass controller parameters in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I write a message and when pressing the send option,
I want to store `student_id`, `coach_id` and `message` to the database. `student_id` and `coach_id` are being saved, but the `message` field is not being saved. It shows null in the database. How do I fix this?

Any help is appreciated.

Controller file:

```
class CourseQueriesController <ApplicationController
  def index 
    @course_query = CourseQuery.new
  end

  def create
    # @course_query = CourseQuery.new(course_query_params)
    @course_query = CourseQuery.where(student_id: current_student.id, coach_id: "2", message: params[:message]).first_or_create 
    if @course_query.save
      redirect_to course_queries_path, notice: 'Query was successfully send.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_course_query
    @course_query = CourseQuery.find(params[:id])
  end

  # def course_query_params
  #   params[:course_query].permit(:message)
  # end
end
```

model/course_query.rb:

```
class CourseQuery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :coach
end
```

view/course_query/index.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for (@course_query) do |f| %>
<%= f.button :submit , "Send or press enter"%>
<%= f.input :message %>
<% end %>
```

database /course_queries:
[image]

Comment: Can you show your controller? Do you maybe have unpermitted parameter messages in the server log when submitting the form?

Comment: i edited my above code.please check

Comment: please show all params sent to the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look into the `params` generated in the log, you will see that the `message` inside the `course_query` hash, so `params[:message]` should be `params[:course_query][:message]`

```
@course_query = CourseQuery.where(student_id: current_student.id, coach_id: "2", message: params[:course_query][:message]).first_or_create
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems you didn't permit `:course_query`.

Try to permit your params the following way:

```
 def course_query_params
   params.require(:course_query).permit(:message)
 end
```

But according to the 2nd way you pass params (`params[:message]`) I think you have a bit different params structure. So try another one:

```
 def course_query_params
   params.permit(:message)
 end
```

Comment: not working ,i tried this , then also it storing null value. if i pass static value in message that is storing. but dynamic is not storing :(

Comment: could you show all params that are send to controller?

Comment: I see you have `:message` key at the params root so I updated the answer

Comment: i tried this also , not working, i updated my code above please check